# RestTemplate reads String data with "\" content (Even with StringHttpMessageConverter)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-mvc-test

I am working with Spring Framework `4.3.6.RELEASE`

For testing purposes through `RestTemplate` how a consumer, if the HTTP `DELETE` method fails because the entity does not exist, I need return an error message in raw format or `String`. It because 'normally' `DELETE` does not require mandatorily neither `Accept` nor `Content-Type`. I don't want complicate the user setting the `Accept` either for `XML` or `JSON`

My `@Test` method fails with the following error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "The entity does not exist"
     but: was "\"The entity does not exist\""
```

Observe the `\"` part

In the server side, I have declared:

```
@Bean
public StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter(){
        StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return converter;
}
```

And is registered:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.stringHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

With a `@ControllerAdvice`, working together with a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`, a `ResponseEntity<Object>` object is created with the following approach in some place to establish the `Content-Type`

```
if(httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.DELETE.toString())){
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

When I print the error message in the server side it prints without `\"` part

The `RestTemplate` for testing purposes is created with:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(mockMvc));
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(customConverters);
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(restTemplateResponseErrorHandler);
```

Therefore why the `\"` part arrives to `RestTemplate`? 
How it can be fix it.? What missing configuration is need it?

**Alpha**

Test Class declaration

```
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ActiveProfiles(resolver=TestActiveProfilesResolver.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class PersonaDeleteOneRestControllerClientBadRequestTest {
```

Some variables in that class:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
private RestTemplateClientSupport restTemplateClientSupport;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private static RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler restTemplateResponseErrorHandler;
```

Some creations:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp_(){
    restTemplateResponseErrorHandler = new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler();
}

@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    restTemplate = restTemplateClientSupport.deleteOneBadRequest(mockMvc);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(restTemplateResponseErrorHandler);
}
```

The `RestTemplate` part is:

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateClientSupport {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestTemplateClientSupport.class.getSimpleName());

private final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> customConverters;

@Autowired
public RestTemplateClientSupport(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> customConverters){
    this.customConverters = customConverters;
}

private RestTemplate createRestTemplateWithListHttpMessageConverter(MockMvc mockMvc){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(mockMvc));

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(converter -> {
        if(converter.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.class.getSimpleName())){
            logger.info("Removing: {}" , converter.getClass().getSimpleName());
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(converter -> {
        if(converter.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class.getSimpleName())){
            logger.info("Removing: {}" , converter.getClass().getSimpleName());
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(converter -> {
        if(converter.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(StringHttpMessageConverter.class.getSimpleName())){
            logger.info("Removing: {}" , converter.getClass().getSimpleName());
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().addAll(customConverters);
    return restTemplate;
```

**Note:** I am using `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().removeIf(Predicate<>..` because I need remove these 3 default converters and add my own one created.

Comment: Could you please post the complete test code (*especially the construction of `mockMvc` and `customConverters`*)

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond done, see **Alpha** section

Comment: Thanks! However the `customConverters` which will be used in `RestTemplateClientSupport` will be key part here. Please share those as well. :)

Comment: They are the three same added manually in the `configureMessageConverters` method. But in this case they are retrieved through `@Autowired` being used in an instance variable of `List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>` type.